# Using Zookeeper Znodes to dynamically change storm bolt processes

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am creating a storm based project where messages will be filtered by storm. My aim is to allow a user to adapt the filtering performed at runtime by sending configuration information to a zookeeper Znode.

I believe this is possible by setting a zookeeper watcher up within storm but I am struggling to achieve this. I would be gratefull for some guidance or a simple example on how to perfrom this.

I have looked at the Java docs and afraid the way to perfrom this does not seem obvious